# Is it possible to return a calculated field from a MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb

In SQL I could do something like

```
SELECT myNum, (myNum+1) as `increment` FROM myTable
```

effectively doing arbitrary math and other functions and returning those as a field in the result. Can the same be done with MongoDB?

```
db.test.find({}, {_id:1, myNum:1, increment:function() { return this.myNum + 1;}});
```

That does not return an "increment" field like I'd expect.

All other related questions I could find on this topic deal with GROUPed queries, which this one is not; I'm just adding a "virtual" field to the document when it's fetched (client-side computed?).

Alternately, this problem seems to be a "map" without a "reduce"; each row has its own calculated field. Is there any way to return the result of a map function as a result/cursor?

Answer (score 13):

The new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2 allows you to add calculated fields via the [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_project) operator.  This isn't quite the same as *arbitrary* functions because you need to use [supported operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/), but it does provide a good deal of flexibility.

Here is your example of incrementing `_id`s into a new `myNum` field:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0-rc0

> db.test.insert({_id:123});

> db.test.insert({_id:456});

> db.test.aggregate(
  { $project : {
      _id : 1,
     'myNum': { $add: [ "$_id", 1]}
  }}
)
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 123,
            "myNum" : 124
        },
        {
            "_id" : 456,
            "myNum" : 457
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Well that looks promising. Though the documentation lists version 2.1 as the first version with that feature, not 2.2. Unfortunately it doesn't have a `$count` function; for my real-world purposed, I have to do a count on a sub-document array. That and the Fedora 16 repos only have 2.0 currently, so I might have to do this client-side

Comment: @MidnightLightning: you are correct that the aggregation framework first appeared in the 2.1.x development releases.  2.2.0 will be the stable/production release with this feature.  2.2.0rc0 has been [available from mongodb.org/downloads](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) since mid-July.  You can't achieve your example of a field calculated from a single document with a map/reduce because the reduce() function will not be called unless the map emits more than one document for a given key.

Comment: @MidnightLightning: Worth noting that the [MongoDB 2.2.0 production release](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/) has now been available since the end of August, 2012.