# Mongoexport to return computed column

Tags: mongodb

Can I use mongoexport to export a computed column? I want to double the "Score" while returning. I can use Excel do this on my csv. But I wanted to know if mongoexport natively supports this. I tried the following but it didn't work. It returned Score itself: 
`mongoexport -d MyDB -c MyCollection -f _id, FirstName , Score*2 --csv --out f:\NewScores.csv`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909760/is-it-possible-to-return-a-calculated-field-from-a-mongodb-query) similar question. But it's about `find()` where I can achieve this using `$project`.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that mongoexport can perform any caluclation or manipulation of data while exporting it. Its just dumps/export the data from DB to a file. Straight and simple.