# How to arithmetically combine fields in Mongo query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with records like so:

```
{
"scores" : {
    "x" : 1,
    "y" : 2
},
}
```

and I would like to be able to query the collection to return records where the combination of the score values meets or exceeds criteria.  For example, find all records where the sum of score.x and score.y exceeds a threshold value.

I want to avoid pre-calculating the value if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following aggregation code should do the trick

```
db.<your_collection>.aggregate([{$project : { "sum" : {$add:["$scores.x", "$scores.y"]}}},{$match:{sum:{$gte:<threshold_value>}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I need!

Comment: This works as long as the result fits in the maximum document size. I may have to use map-reduce after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operators/) which contains arithmetic operators. Look at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909760/is-it-possible-to-return-a-calculated-field-from-a-mongodb-query).

Comment: Using aggregation will fall down unless the result fits inside the maximum document size.

Answer (score 0):

According to this discussion, you can use map/reduce:

```
db.runCommand({
        "mapreduce": "coll",
        "map": function() { 
                emit({id:this.id},{ 
                        x: this.x,
                        y: this.y
                     });  
        },
        "reduce": function(key,vals) { 
                return 1; 
        },
        "out": { 
                inline : 1 
        },
        "finalize": function(key, vals) {
                return { sum: vals.x + vals.y};
        }
});
```

Comment: The map-reduce step would have to be run first.. which I would like to avoid.

Comment: FYI, after changing "coll" to match my collection, this doesn't work.  It returns one result (instead one for each record) and the value of sum is NaN

Comment: You need to change this part also: `{id:this.id}` to something unique

Comment: I changed {id:this.id} to this:_id and x: this.x, y: etc to scores: this.scores (matching the schema in the question), sum: vals.scores.x + vals.scores.y and now things look better.